# How do use PlasticSCM to revert to previous versions of Unity Project like Unity Collab?

Tags: unity-game-engine, plasticscm

Unity forced me to switch from Collaborate to PlasticSCM. I used Collaborate to upload builds of my game to the cloud, so that I could expirement with new features and stuff that I could easily roll back if they didn't work. This has become very useful for me as my project increases in complexity, because often I'm adding methods or 1-2 lines or code in 5-6 different scripts with hundreds of lines, and if I don't like the way something's turning out after an hour of work for example I could've just, back when collab was a thing, upload the changes and then revert back to the previous version. Say I liked a few things I did when I added said expirmental feature, I could always upload the new version of me adding the feature, go back to the old version, copy for example a few lines of code, and go back to the new version. It was really handy.

**If you look at attatched images, PlasticSCM does something similar with their "Changs ets", and I'm looking for a way to tell it to revert my project back to a previous one.**

[image]

If you still don't get what I'm saying, let's say I added in a folder with 3 textures. Then, upload the changes. Next, I alter the texture. I don't like how I've altered it. The button I'm looking for in PlasticSCM would revert my project to the previous version with the unaltered texture.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [snapshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVpGe.png) view you can right click and select "Switch workspace to this changeset"

You might need to update to the lates version of the "Version Control" plugin.